# cannot switch to root

Tags: sudo, su

I cannot do "sudo su"
It says "Cannot execute /bin/bash: No such file or directory".
I have not bash file at /bin/bash.
Please let me know how to recover it.
I tried copying it from other system or running apt-get install bash, but that require root permissions, and I am unable to "sudo su"

Comment: Which shell is root using by default? (e.g. use `chsh` or `cat /etc/passwd`).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `su` suffix to use sudo. Just do `sudo apt-get install ......`. 
The real question, however, is how your installation lost `bash` and what else could you be missing. And what shell are you using instead?